Reynolds number for Damping Ratio of Sloshing Liquid
I am trying to find an equation for the damping ratio $\zeta$ of sloshing liquid. It is given by the following equation as per 2 of NASAs paper:

Validation of High-Resolution CFD Method for Slosh
Damping Extraction of Baffled Tanks
Prediction of Liquid Slosh Damping Using a High
Resolution CFD Tool

$$ \zeta = 0.79\sqrt{Re} $$
where
$$ Re = \frac{\nu}{\sqrt{gR^3}} $$
where $\nu$ is the kinematic viscosity of the liquid, g is acceleration due to gravity $9.8ms^{-2}$ and R is the radius of the sloshing container.
While this equation seems to be true for experimental values, I do not quite understand where this equation for reynolds number came from. It would be very grateful if someone could find a corresponding journal or paper on this topic. Thank you.

It's empirical.  Dimensional analysis shows that xi is a function of h/R and their Reynolds number parameter.

What is meant by a function of h/R? It is true that both the reynolds number and the damping ratio zeta are dimensionless.
